# How do I undo committed changes on Git?

Tags: git, logging, commit, revert

I'm trying to restore my stable tag by removing the most recent commit. I ran this command:

```
git revert e64218b5d415419043002e67115f81bff05bde0e
```

This appeared:

```
    error: Your local changes would be overwritten by revert.
    hint: Commit your changes or stash them to proceed.
    fatal: revert failed
```

I left this message and closed the file. After verifying that `crazy.html` was gone, I took a look at my history with `git log --oneline`

```
e64218b Add a crazzzy experiment
2d0b4b6 Add navigation links
35a79d5 Create blue and orange pages
f72749b Create index page
```

Why didn't Git figure out how to undo the changes that it contained? Why didn't Git tack on another commit with the resulting content?

Edit - Git status shows:

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

deleted:    crazy.html
```

Comment: what does git status shows?

Comment: I tried it and got the same error

Comment: Do you want the file (crazy.html) to be deleted?

Comment: I want Git to tack on the commit: Revert "Add a crazzzy experiment"

Comment: You'll need to either:
a) First commit the deleted file
b) Unstage and remove the deleted file

Comment: Your working directory was dirty when you tried to `git revert`, this is why Git refused to do the revert and it failed.  Just remove the deleted file and try again.

Answer (score 0):

you can do `git stash`, `git pull`, and `git stash pop`